# Minimizing the integral of a function

Tags: calculus, contest-math

> For what real values of the argument $a$ the area which is limited by
> the function
> $$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R;\ f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}-x^2+a;\ x=0; x=2; y=0$$ is minimum.
>
> (National Mathematical Olympiad)

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Do you mean "algebraic area" or geometric one? The latter means the integral of the negative part of a function must be multplied by -1 and is thus always positive, whereas the former can be any number...

Comment: it involves taking the absolute value whenever necessary

Comment: Numerical computation puts the answer at 4/3.

Comment: I deduced that there are 3 cases:$ a<0, a>\frac{4}{3}                      $ and $ a \in (0, \frac{4}{3})$

Comment: well, the answer is indeed $\frac{2}{3}$ but i am not quite sure  whether the way Brian Silva solved it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording on your question isn't completely clear to me, but I'll answer as best as I can.
Assuming that you want to minimize physical area, the smallest it can be is zero. By evaluating the integral and setting it equal to zero, you can obtain the value of $a$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
0&=\int_0^2 \frac{1}{3}x^3-x^2+a \, dx \\
0&=\frac{1}{12}x^4-\frac{1}{3}x^3+ax\Big|_0^2 \\
0&=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{8}{3}+2a \\
\frac{4}{3}&=2a
\end{align*}

So $a$ should equal $\frac{2}{3}$.